# Asp.NetCore Identity - Create custom token provider

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

So I'm trying to create a custom token by using `UserManager<TUser>.GenerateUserTokenAsync(TUser user, string tokenProvider, string purpose)` method but I keep getting an error when I try to generate the token.

I know the purpose can be just plain text declaring what the token is used for and needs to be the same when validating it later. So my guess is that the `tokenProvider` is the problem.

After doing some research I got to the conclusion that I need to declare my own `tokenProvider` in `Startup.cs` but the information I found doesn't seem to work for me.

Can anyone provide a bit of insight here on how to go about implementing a `custom tokenProvider`? And if my research is wrong, how do I make this work?

Comment: Thank you for the info! Read through it and got the token provider up and running

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-identity-token-providers

Read through the documentation, it's quite clear.

I simply had to add `.AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<Entity>>("purpose")` to my `services.AddIdentity<Entity, IdentityRole>()` in start.cs

The `("purpose")` can be anything you want it to be. I just needed it to validate some user input before making changes to the entity.